# set default apn on android 4 Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, apn

Is there a way to set the **default apn** programmatically on android 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich).
It was possible on android 2.3 but doesn't work  anymore with 4. 
Now there is always an errormessage:

**java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write APN settings: Neither user 10142 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS., Could not set default access point!**

The "WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" permission is still in the manifest.

I heard that creating new apns isn't possible anymore with 4, but what about just setting the default apn?